# import "." is a program, not an importable package

Tags: visual-studio, go, import, grpc, gateway

**I'm trying to create a tools.go for gRPC in Golang, basically creating REST API based on gRPC with Gateway. However I'm trying to put imports in the `package main` in the tools.go folder. Here is the code in question:**

```
//go:build tools
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    _ "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway"
    _ "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2"
    _ "google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc"
    _ "google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go"
)
```

And it prompts the error

`import "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway" is a program, not an importable package`

the blank identifier or the `_` in the code is highlighted red as well.

[Here's The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIJwJ.png)

**What I've tried so Far**

- installed all the needed packages/libraries and did `go tidy mod`(following the installation steps in https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway)
- executed a `go generate .\...` in order to find for dependencies for those imports

A friend of mine also did the same procedures and it worked for them. Could it also be an environment-based issue? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Is there anyway for me to make it work? I'm currently following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SnC354B5Vc which what I am trying to do.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: The tutorial is following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#installation) from the repo. The build constraint (`//go:build tools`) means this file will be excluded when you run `go build` (the file only exists to enable tracking of [tool dependencies](https://go.dev/wiki/Modules#how-can-i-track-tool-dependencies-for-a-module)). You should not be adding anything else to the file; put your code in another `.go` file. If this does not help please tell us what you are doing that results in the error being displayed (you can ignore the Vscode warning).

Comment: There is no "error" you just have some problems with your editor. Btw: Remove the +build tools line; its almost 2024.

Comment: @BurakSerdar This is allowed, and it's the convention for dev dependencies. https://go.dev/wiki/Modules#how-can-i-track-tool-dependencies-for-a-module https://play-with-go.dev/tools-as-dependencies_go119_en/

Comment: @weberc2, so I learned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but, there is nothing wrong here. It's just an editor warning which you can ignore as per https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/3515.

You've followed the installation exactly as it is stated in the documentation/[github](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#installation) page. After you've run go mod tidy and other additional set up specific to your project, you'll find that you can then generate code using protoc/protobuf with no issue.